# Get or Set Accessor of Attached Property not firing on databind? WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, properties, attached-properties

I have a custom Attached Property but the Accessors on never being accessed on databinding.
Are theses accessors meant to be accessed everytime the attached property changes?

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CharacterColumnNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CharacterColumnNumber", typeof(int), typeof(DragCanvas), new UIPropertyMetadata(1));

    public static int GetCharacterColumnNumber(UIElement uiElement)
    {
        if (uiElement != null)
            return (int)uiElement.GetValue(CharacterColumnNumberProperty);
        else return 0;
    }

    public static void SetCharacterColumnNumber(UIElement uiElement, int value)
    {
        if (uiElement != null)
        {
            uiElement.SetValue(CharacterColumnNumberProperty, value);
            DragCanvas.SetLeft(uiElement, value * 10);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
 <Setter Property="local:DragCanvas.CharacterColumnNumber" Value="{Binding Path=CharacterColumnNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Bindings don't access the properties--they use the underlying dependency object and binding frameworks to access the values of dependency properties.  This one surprised me, too, when I first started messing around with DP's.  There's lots of stuff under the covers in WPF.

Comment: Why does the framework ( or xaml editor) need the accessors to conform to the naming convention if they are not even used by the WPF Property system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not. If you want to know when the internal property engine is changing these values you pass in a delegate for the [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) parameter of the UIPropertyMetadata.

This delegate will be invoked each time the property is changed, whether it came through the CLR property or via changes internally in the dependency property engine (i.e. bindings).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense.
But as I understood attached properties is that one of there most frequent uses is to change the layout. 
Would the PropertyChangedCallback parameter give me the best option to change the Canvas.Left of the UIElement when the CharacterColumnNumber changes? ie: Canvas.Left = CharacterColumnNumber * 10.
Just to reiterate, I would like to tie up the CharacterColumnNumber value to the location on the canvas.

Comment: After writing the last comment I thought of using a converter, maybe a better option? But if I did not want to use a converter would the above be the best way? Thanks.